# How can I use the Rails "find" method to perform an AND or an OR query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's assume I have a model called "product."  Let's assume that product has three fields.  These fields are 'name' (type string), 'cost' (type integer), and 'is_visible' (type bool).

1) How can I do a search query using the Rails "find" method (if there is another method, that's fine) so that I can search for all products with a cost greater than 100 AND is_visible is true?

2) What if we wanted to change this to search to where name != '' OR cost == 0?

This isn't a problem to do an SQL, but I would like to think that Rails has a way to do AND/OR queries to the database without using SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would need to use the conditions option on the find method.  The conditions option can be either a Hash, Array, or String.  There are lots of options for conditions, so I recommend reading the [API help](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) for it.
For example if you want to (1):

```
Product.find(:all, :conditions => ['cost > ? and is_visible is true', 100])
```

Or (2)

```
Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["name != '' or cost =0])
```

Comment: According to rails api doc it should 'be = true' but Adam you seem to have missed the point in your answers and here that it's a Rails question no a SQL question. For many of us the Rails way is just easier and better.

Comment: Actually everything you include in :conditions will be embedded directly into the SELECT statement generated by ActiveRecord - so this definitely has something to do with SQL.

Comment: I think the .where method is more appropriate now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find

Answer (score 4):

If you want something like LINQ you can check alternative Ruby ORMs like [DataMapper](http://www.datamapper.org/doku.php?id=docs:finders) or [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html) that provide more complex filtering capabilities.

For example in Sequel 2 you can write:

```
items.filter((:cost > 100) & (:is_visible = 1))
```

You can also use the bitwise "|" operator to get OR condition.

In DataMapper this will look like:

```
Model.all(:cost.gt => 100, :is_visible.eq => 1)
```

However some people don't like the fact that those features are implemented by overloading the standard Symbol class.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the problem SQL was designed to solve, so why not to use it? Just add an appropriate :condition and your problem is solved.

Comment: Because I have been spoiled by LINQ.

Comment: I see, so I elaborated on this in my second answer - hope that helps.

Comment: The fact this was downvoted only convinces me to the surprising fact that most Rails developers are afraid of SQL. This is interesting, as SQL is a great example of an external DSL, and Rails folks generally like DSLs.