# Rails .where vs .find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've noticed that the `Model.where` method always returns an array even if there is only one result where as the `Model.find` method doesn't. Is there any reason for this? I thought `Model.where` was the preferred function since Rails 3.X.

Should I be using `Model.find` when I expect a single result and `Model.where` when I expect more than one result?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

- [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) returns an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) (not an array, even though it behaves much like one), which is a *collection* of model objects. If nothing matches the conditions, it simply returns an empty relation.
- [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) (and its related dynamic `find_by_columnname` methods) returns a *single* model object. If nothing is found, an [`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html) exception is raised (but not with the dynamic `find_by_` methods).

  While `find` can return an Array of records—not a Relation—if given a list of IDs, using `where` is preferred since Rails 3. Many similar uses of `find` are now [deprecated or gone entirely](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations).

So yes, if you only want and expect a single object, using `find` is easier, as otherwise you must call `Model.where.first`.

Note that old-style hash options to `find` and many dynamic `find_` methods are deprecated as of Rails 4.0 ([see relevant release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)).

Comment: i think that `find` can return several objects in an array - try `User.find [1,2,3]` (finds users with ids 1, 2 and 3)... but yeah i guess andrew is right about the rest

Comment: @klump Yup, it can, but `User.where(id: [1, 2, 3])` is preferred in that case so I didn't even consider it. As always I recommend reading the API documentation (which I've linked to in my answer), as it provides the most detail.

Comment: But `.find(:all, ...)` returns an array. So what is the difference between find and where?

Comment: @highBandWidth See above comments. I've also updated my answer. `where` doesn't return an Array (even though `Model.where(...).class` will lie and say it is).

Answer (score 14):

Actually `find_by` takes a model object from `where` obtained `ActiveRecord::Relation`

```
def find_by(*args)
  where(*args).take
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1660f53dabb6eee71f64b0f552ed120880a2f8ea/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L47)

Comment: Note that find_by was not added until Rails 4 (original question was tagged rails 3).

Answer (score 7):

`Model.find` is using the primary key column. Therefore there is always exactly one or no result. Use it when you are looking for one specific element identified by it's id.

Comment: Not if you do `.find(:conditions => {:col_name => some_vals})`.