# .find or where condition in active record querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am confused on where to use '.find' and where to use 'where'. is there a difference in the performance during the execution of the query ??

example : converted the existing queries which are using .find as below :

`FileOrFolder.find_by_fullpath(completePath, :select=>"id")`   -->

```
FileOrFolder.where(fullpath: completePath).select(:id).first
```

`Component.find(:first, :conditions=>["cluster_id = ? AND name = ?", cluster_id, key])`  -->

```
Component.where(cluster_id: cluster_id, name: key).first
```

Comment: No difference in performance - same queries, but more "handy" to use `where` because of the returned ActiveRecord::Relation ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find )

Comment: @MrYoshiji ... i have gone through this post .... no where it talks about the query performance right .....pls correct me if am wrong

Comment: You could just do it yourself by testing in your console `Component.where(id: 1).first` and `Component.find(1)`, you would see  that is produces the EXACT same queries and take the EXACT same time because they are ... the same queries!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are all equivalent.  What you're seeing here is the evolution of the ActiveRecord query syntax from before [AREL](https://github.com/rails/arel) was incorporated.  The older style dynamic finders are still valid, though.

This syntax is from ROR 2.x and earlier using dynamic finders:

```
FileOrFolder.find_by_fullpath(completePath, :select=>"id")
```

Whereas these are more in the ROR 3.x style:

```
FileOrFolder.where(fullpath: completePath).select(:id).first
Component.where(cluster_id: cluster_id, name: key).first
```

And your last example using `find` is valid in either context.

```
Component.find(:first, :conditions=>["cluster_id = ? AND name = ?", cluster_id, key])
```

When in doubt, [consult the ROR query guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

I personally find the `where` styles are very useful when you're building up a query over several lines of code and not all at once.  Since they defer execution until the latest moment, they let you build the query piecemeal.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a significant performance difference because usually they will both generate the same SQL, e.g.:

```
Article.find_by_headline('foo')
=> SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`headline` = 'foo' LIMIT 1

Article.where(headline: 'foo').first
=> SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`headline` = 'foo' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: so you mean to say ...its just a syntax difference overall ..... as some find_by_headline type of syntax is being deprecated, we are tending to use where .... thts it right ?

Comment: @Vinay, `find_by` is _not_ being deprecated, just those other variations. My preference is to use whichever syntax is more clear & concise for the current case, with the tie going to `where`. In practice I use both. I think that's more personal aesthetics than a uniform best practice though.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer `where` style going forward, Rails 4 has deprecated use of `find_by_` - see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

Comment: From your link: 

All dynamic methods *except* for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated. Here's how you can rewrite the code: