# Get rails ActiveRecord instead of Array of objects for multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table that stores queries that return a list of users.
I then have a method "get_public" to a "Banana" model that execute multiple queries using logic AND between them.

So, when I do

`Banana.find(x).get_public` I receive an Array of users (the ones suitable to that banana object).

The get_public method is like this:

```
def get_public
  pb = []
  banana_queries.each do |q|
    pb << User.find_by_sql(q.query)
  end
  pb.inject(:'&')
end
```

But, would be great if I could get ActiveRecord::Relation instead. I want to do something like this after: `Banana.find(x).get_public.where(...)`
Any way to modify get_public and achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried including `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods` in your class to get relation query methods?

Comment: What is `pb.inject(:'&')` supposed to be doing in this case and have you tested it's behavior?

Comment: it's the "logic AND" between the itens of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I correcly undestood the problem, but I will try to help anyway.

As especified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find)

- where returns an ActiveRecord::Relation
- find (and its related dynamic methods) returns a single model object

So I suggest divide your queries into: 'joins' and 'where' fields. Your new code should look like something like this:

```
 pb << User.joins(q.query_joins).where(q.query_where)
```

Also find methods will are deprecated in rails 4, so using where is recommended.

Hope I haven't missed the point too much :-)