# error with my ruby on rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i´ve made an application on ROR but when i send the params to the database for check it out,and see if i can continue to the other form, will appear a error.....

the error it´s this:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

the form where the user write a barcode(this is the params we have to compare in the database) says this:

```
<p>INGRESE EL CÓDIGO DE BARRA DEL PRODUCTO QUE DESEA AGREGAR:</p>
            <input type="text" name="codigo"><br>
            <a href="#"><input type="submit" name="reset" value="Buscar"></a>
            <% @medicinas.each do |p| %> 
            <% if codigo.text == @p.codigobarras %>
            INGRESE OTRO CÓDIGO DE BARRAS, EL QUE ESTA UTILIZANDO YA SE ENCUENTRA ALMACENADO
            <% else %>
              AGREGAR MEDICAMENTO
```

and my application controller have this:

```
@medicinas = Medicamentos.find params( [:codigobarras]).
```

what i´m doing wrong??

Comment: `params( [:codigobarras]).`? Have you looked at *any* Rails tutorial? the correct use of `find` and `params` is **everywhere**.

Comment: @mbratch The `params(...)` will produce the error described. `params` is a method which takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @mbratch No, `params` is a method on `ActionController::Base` which returns a hash. Try it yourself, it's trivially easy. `params(123)` will cause the same error he's seeing: "Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)".

Comment: @meagar sorry, my mistake

Comment: @medicinas = Medicamentos.find params[:codigobarras]

Comment: Also it will only work if "codigobarras" is a integer so ActiveRecord will search on ID column for the "codigobarras" value

Comment: @meagar what did you mean with params(123), i´ve seen a few rails tutorials but i continue with some doubt, what can i do to fix this mistake?, by the way, i don´t know to much about rails, i am learning

Comment: @FelipeSkinner, rails only look for the column of ID?? i wanna make it search on codigobarras column, because the user will write a barcode on a text box (<input type="text" name="codigo">) and then the application compare that code with the database and if the code already exists, then the user see a message (like this "INGRESE OTRO CÓDIGO DE BARRAS, EL QUE ESTA UTILIZANDO YA SE ENCUENTRA ALMACENADO") and if not, then appear a link for a new form to add the product

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "find" method is for ID. If you want to search by other columns you should use ".where" instead

Comment: @FelipeSkinner, how can i make it? I want the user can write the numbers from product barcode in a text box, and this was compared in the database to see if it exists, and then if there is send the form to add new product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
@medicinas = Medicamentos.where("codigobarras = ?", params[:codigobarras])
```

Take a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Or you could use the 'find_by' method as of here:
[Rails .where vs .find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find)

That would be like this:

```
@medicinas = Medicamentos.find_by_codigobarras params[:codigobarras]
```

Comment: i use the statement you suggested but now, when i prove the app, and write a bar code, the if statement doesn´t work, i think that´s the problem because don´t show me any message...and by the way, thanks for the tutorial to learn how to use the active record...

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't understand your new problem tho... Could you explain a little so I can try to help?

Comment: my problem is because in this textbox "<input type="text" name="codigo">" the user must write a barcode, and when press this button ("<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Buscar">") the app must compare the barcode on the textbox with the database "Medicamentos.codigobarras", and if the barcode in the textbox is the same than database, the app show a message telling to the user " INGRESE OTRO CÓDIGO DE BARRAS, EL QUE ESTA UTILIZANDO YA SE ENCUENTRA ALMACENADO" and if not is stored in database, then show a link to go to the next form, for add that product.

Comment: to continue, well, the message before this i tell you what i want to make....but when i write on the text box and press the button, the app don´t do nothing....just stay in the same form.... i think my if statement is wrong, because i wrote the statement you suggested me and don´t show me any error, but don´t do what i wanna do.

Comment: If this is a form and you want to have unique barcode you should use "validate :uniqueness => true" on your model instead of searching manually on your controller

Comment: i do what you suggested, but i´m still stuck, if exists a way to send the pictures of my app, i can do it and send to you, besides, even if i try to work with a ActiveRecord form, doesn´t work either...i mean, the app is working, because add and show all the products but, i wanna have a textbox to check in the database if a product already exists, that statement is the one who got me stuck

Answer (score 0):

Done!, first of all thanks for your help.

this is how i make it

on my controller:

```
  @codigo = params[:codigobarras]
  @medicinas = Medicamentos.find_by_codigobarras(@codigo)
```

with all this, the app make what i wanna...i just initialize a variable named "codigo" and this variable will take the params of codigobarras and then can compare with "medicinas"