# Rails - I can access object in console but not in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

UserNotification belongs_to User and User has_many UserNotification.

I am trying to access the notifications through the user. If I run in the console:

```
User.find(31).user_notifications
```

It returns the following user:

```
<Employer id: 31, email: "person1@commercial.com", ...>
```

The code above is correct (A user can be of type 'employer' or 'freelancer'.  I believe this is called polymorphic).  However, if I run:

```
User.where(email: 'person1@commercial.com').user_notifications
```

I am told that:

```
undefined method `user_notifications'
```

This should give me the same user as the 'find' method I use above.  In my application, I am having the same problem referring to the user_notification when using current_user.  For example, I have:

```
@notifications = current_user.user_notifications.inspect
```

I do this while logged in as the same user I was working with in the console, User 31.  However, the user_notifications are displayed as nil.

How do I access user_notification through current_user?

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the console problem.  Why is that?  I definitely only have one user with that email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.where` returns an array.  So when you use it you need to specify which result you want:

```
User.where(email: 'person1@commercial.com').first.user_notifications
```

See this question for a detailed explanation:[Rails .where vs .find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find)

Comment: Thanks, how do i get it to work in the application with current_user?

Comment: I think you would have to provide more code, like how do you return `current_user`?  If you get `current_user` by using `where` it is the same situation.

Comment: I'm not sure, current_user is a helper from devise.

Comment: That is very strange, if you are using devise it should work without `.first`.  The only thing I can think is that when you call current_user you haven't saved the model with the `user_notifications` property yet, so it doesn't exist yet.