# Rails 3.2 Sum Integers in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My view lists a set of expenses, I would like to sum the values in the current view.  This is the code I am trying in my controller.

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@expense_list = @project.expenses.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id).sort_by(&:expense_date)
@expense_total = @expense_list.sum(:amount)
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined method `+' for #<Expense:0x007f907a2ba888>
```

Any advice?  I feel like I'm doing something wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@expense_total = @project.expenses.where(:user_id => current_user.id).sum(:amount)
```

Comment: fantastic, so simple, yet so not how I thought to do it :)

Comment: here you can find your answer. I hope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find