# Ruby on Rails: Update Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-console

Google is seriously failing me right now. All I need to do is update one attribute, setting a user to admin, from the Heroku rails console.

I can't find a single simple answer. What I've been trying is:

`Record.update_attribute(:roles_mask, "1")`

Where record is the correct record.

> 'undefined method 'update attribute''

I can't just type `Record.roles_mask = 1`?

EDIT.

I used Record, and I shouldn't have done that in the example. What I've done is exactly this:

```
ian = User.where(:id => '5')

ian.update_attribute(:roles_mask, '1')

Error: undefined method 'update_attributes'
```

Comment: Are you trying to update one or all?

Comment: Call `update_attribute` on the `instance` of Record class not on class `Record`. `update_attribute` is an instance method not a class method.

Comment: try using `update_columns` instead of `update_attributes`

Comment: If update one `record = Record.find(...); record.update_attribute(:roles_mask, "1")`.  If update all, `Record.update_all(:roles_mask, "1")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that using the `.where` function creates a relation, rather than finding the record itself. Do this:

```
ian = User.find(5)
ian.update_attribute(:roles_mask, '1')
```

Or if you want to use `.where` then you could do this:

```
ian = User.where(:id => 5)
ian.first.update_attribute(:roles_mask, '1')
```

EDIT

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find) for details about why this is happening.

Comment: As a side note for future google searches, another issue was that the variable I was using was protected. I had to allow mass-assignment. attr_accessible :roles_mask.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3):

To use update_attribute (or update_attributes), you need to call that from an instance and not the class.

```
rails c> rec = Record.find(1)
rails c> rec.update_attribute(:att, 'value')
rails c> rec.update_attributes(att: 'value', att2: 'value2')
```

I would think that should take care of your issue.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have
ian = User.where(:id => '5')
ian.update_attribute(:roles_mask, '1')

error: undefined method 'update_attribute'

Also, thank you for your response. For the record, I am only trying to update 1 record.

Comment: The problem there is that where() returns an ActiveRecord relation. Try either of the following: ian = User.find(5) or ian = User.where(id: 5).first ... ignore. Just saw that @Mike Slutsky said as much.

Answer (score 1):

Where clause return a array and you are trying to make update query on array, that's why you got error.

you should try to find out first record

```
ian = User.where(:id => 1).first
or
ian = User.find(1)
or
ian = User.find_by_id(1)
```

now your update query will work.

```
ian.update_attribute(:roles_mask, '1')
```