# Active Record Rails 4 Unique Query on Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My users have many 'received_messages' and 'sent_messages' (from a join table that just contains a receiver_id, sender_id, and the content). My associations are all set up correctly and when I call user.received_messages and user.sent_messages I am returned the correct collections. What I am now trying to do is filter the returned message collections so they will only return the first(newest) message from each unique sender(if it is received_messages) or receiver(if it is sent_messages).

I have tried :

`@sent_messages = @user.sent_messages.uniq(&:receiver_id)
 @sent_messages = @user.sent_messages.select(:receiver_id).distinct`

Etc but this keeps returning to me an array of numbers rather than actual collections.

Not sure if this is relevant but in my User model the associations are set up as :

`has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'receiver_id', table_name: 'messages'
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'sender_id', table_name: 'messages'`

and in the Message model:

`belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: 'sender_id', class_name: "User"
belongs_to :receiver, foreign_key: 'receiver_id', class_name: "User"`

Comment: Can't you `group_by` the `receiver_id` and then by the `sender_id`, with a sort on the messages.created_at (or updated) in order to join the newest message on the sender/receiver? -- Another question, are you using PostGreSQL?

Comment: @MrYoshiji i am using psql yes. i already have the collection of sent_messages (@user.sent_messages, which is not a method i wrote myself but one active record gave me because of the way i set up my relationships), how exactly would i use group_by? I just tried doing user.sent_messages.group(:receiver_id) but it return this error: "PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "messages.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: Use DINSTINCT ON ;) a very nice tool available in PostGre SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
message_per_uniq_receiver = @user.sent_messages.select('DISTINCT ON (receiver_id) *')
                                               .order('receiver_id, messages.created_at DESC')

message_per_uniq_sender = @user.received_messages.select('DISTINCT ON (sender_id) *')
                                                 .order('sender_id, messages.created_at DESC')
```

This `DISTINCT ON` is kinda complex ( [documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) ):

Long story short, the `DISTINCT ON(sender_id)` will create groups for each distinct `sender_id` found in the messages table, and will select the first of each group, the first of the group is determined by the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: yes!! thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for! I started reading about DISTINCT ON but when I saw that it was PSQL syntax I kept trying to look for an active record specific way to do it (i.e. trying .distinct, .uniq) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The "select" method is like the SELECT command in SQL. It selects a database column and returns data.

Thus, `sent_messages.select(:receiver_id)` returns the receiver ID, which is an integer.

If you want sent_messages with a particular receiver ID, use the "where" method.

For example, `sent_messages.where(receiver_id: some_receiver_id)`.

Comment: Sometimes you might use "find_by" instead of "where". There are subtle differences between them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find

Comment: @jdev because of the way i set up the relationships user.sent_messages returns the correct collection (every message the user has ever sent). but for the inbox display page I only want it showing the most recent correspondence(only the most recent message the current user sent another specific user). i was wondering if there was any direct way to extract unique records from an already created collection, a way of iterating through each record in the collection and only selecting the most recent ones with uniquer receiver_ids

Comment: OK. I've posted an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with your list of distinct receiver ID's. Call it receiver_id_list. Then iterate through them. For each ID, find the newest message belonging to that receiver, and add it to an array.

```
most_recent_sent_messages = []

receiver_id_list.each do |id|
  most_recent_sent_messages << @user.sent_messages.where(receiver_id: id).order(time_sent: :desc).first
end
```

The highest `time_sent` (or whatever you named the timestamp) should be the newest message, which is why you should sort them in descending order.

Comment: yep! i was just wondering if there was any direct active record method that would allow me to do exactly that