# Showing data from multiple tables in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a system that tracks illnesses and symptoms associated with them through Ruby on Rails. 
I have a "illnesses" table and a "symptoms" table and they have a many_to_many relationship through the "symptoms_illnesses" table. 
For now, I'm working on a page that displays a single entry of the "symptoms_illnesses" table. This table has two columns: illness_id and symptom_id.

I need a way to display the illness and symptom that match the ID.

Example:
"illness" table has "Common Cold" under `id = 1`

"symptom" table has "Fever" under `id = 1`

"symptoms_illness" table has `illness_id = 1` and `symptom_id = 1`.

I want the "symptoms_illness/1" page to display "Common Cold" and "Fever", but I see no obvious way to do it. 
Other topics in this site don't seem to address the problem in a satisfactory way.

**Edit 1:**
I didn't add anything to the show action besides the "default"

```
def show
        @symptoms_illness = Symptoms_illness.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Could you post what's in the `show` action in your `symptoms_illness` controller?

Comment: Added to post, there isn't much there, just the default. The Show page just shows the ids (1 and 1) for now

Comment: `find` returns the first result of a query. To obtain all results, you should use `where`, like so: `@symptoms_illness = Symptoms_illness.where(id: params[:id])`. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find) for more info about `find` and `where`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found out how to do it: 
First, I created `@illness` and `@symptom` instances to the `symptom_illness_controller`. Then, in the `show` action, I added two `find_by_id`. 
Finally, in the Show view, I changed `@symptomillness.illness_id` to `@symptomillness.illness.name`, now it shows up fine.

This may not be the cleanest way to do it but it works for what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
    @symptoms_illness = Symptoms_illness.includes(:illness,:symptom).where(id: params[:id])
end
```

in your view

```
<%= @symptoms_illness.illness.name %>
<%= @symptoms_illness.symptom.name %>
```

PS: not tested

Comment: Seems to give "undefined method 'illness' for for #<Symptomillness::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f51bbb92378>

Comment: can you post the models relationships

Comment: I don't think I have a version of it in English, but the relevant tables for this problem are: 

Illness: int id, string name, string description;
Symptoms: int id, string name, string description;
Symptom_illness: int id, int illness_id, int symptoms_id; 

Many to Many relationship between Symptoms and Illnesses linked by the "S_I" table