# Why `where` method doesn't work, unlike `find`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Faced a problem completely incomprehensible to me.
I am getting an error when using the method `where`.

```rb
@winner = Team.where(id: params[:winner_id])
@winner.update(rating: @winner.rating += 20)
```

```
undefined method `rating' for #<Team::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007faed9018490>
```

However, if I change `@winner = Team.where(id: params[:winner_id])` to `@winner = Team.find(params[:winner_id])`it will work.

Why `where` method doesn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails .where vs .find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `where` always gives you an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, not a single object. In your case you're filtering on the id, so if that's the primary key, as I suppose, you only get one record, but that's into a relation anyway, because that's the semantic of where.

```
@winner = Team.where(id: params[:winner_id]).first
```

or

```
@winner = Team.find_by(id: params[:winner_id])
```

One of these should do the trick

`where` works this way because you could even filter for some not so restrictive columns and get many rows in returns, so you always get a collection of rows. For example, think about this

```
@people = Person.where(age: 20)
```

this query retrieves all the people 20 years old. That could get zero, one or many rows but you always get a relation, for sure.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what it means _always get a relation_. I have used `where` unmeasured number of times and have never encountered this.

Comment: With `where` you don't get a single object but a collection of objects. It's the method's semantic.

Comment: @SsPay: "and have never encountered this" - if this is true, you have never tried to call a method which belongs to a model on a result of `where` before.

Comment: @Ursus: you don't even get a "collection of objects". There are no objects. Instead you get this weird collection-like proxy thingie that goes and fetches data from the db, but only if you attempt to iterate it. If you never iterate, it won't make a query. But this is too fine a level of details, I suppose :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I was trying to keep it is as simple as possible :(

Comment: @Ursus: yeah-yeah, it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck. For practical purposes, it's a duck (collection).

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev I mean I used 'where' along with the primary key (id).  And I expected to get only one result, not an array, since there cannot be two objects with the same id.

Comment: @SsPay that's simply not how `where` works :) if you use `where` you're accepting the fact that what it returns is a collection. Otherwise you use find_by or find or where + first